# Writing proofs using deductive reasoning vs. stating axioms of logic

Tags: logic, proof-writing, soft-question

I started learning set theory and logic, and I'm little confused about the right method to write proofs. I've seen professors use deductive reasoning and rules of inference to write proofs, while others mention axioms and theorems (which are similar to the rules of inference) that you must state before writing a proof. Which is the better method?

Comment: Proofs are usually not "formalized" (some very important results have been verified with a computer program) , but formulated in a "human-readable" way. For example, proving that infinite many primes exist is easy, but a formal proof even for such an easy statement would probably be hard (I must admit however that I am not an expert in "formalizing proofs")

Comment: @Peter I mean of deductive reasoning as a starting point, not formalizing proofs which no one use, there are professors who don't  teach deductive reasoning but start by giving few axioms and theorems that you must state before giving a proof, and I really didn't like this method, deductive reasoning as a start to learn writing proofs make you think more, I'm asking if I'm right on this point?

Comment: You need axioms: you have to start from somewhere, and you need inference rules: to derive theorems from axioms or already proven theorems.